# Sum of duplicate named range across multiple sheets?

Tags: excel

Ive got X amount of sheets in my excel document.  On all sheets, there is a named range of:

> TotalSupportCost

On a master sheet, how can I do something like:

```
Total value of all TotalSupportCost across every worksheet
```

This way, whenever a sheet is duplicated the total will dynamically increase

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately you cannot use something like '=SUM('Sheet1:Sheet3'!testname)', although Excel itself will give that when you hold the shift key and select all sheets...

A worksheet function what you can use to a limited extend is `INDIRECT()` however you still wont be able to learn all the worksheet names of the worksheets in your workbook.

This leaves you to the resort of using VBA. In VBA you can actually loop through all worksheets and retrieve (and sum up) all the values of a certain cell or of a named range. When you make this function `Public` you will be able to call it as if it were a worksheet function itself!

Comment: Ah ok.  I will just had to create 2 new worksheets called start and end.  Put them in place and use those as references and then do the sum of the cell.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: As I said that WILL NOT work if you mean to use Excel worksheet functions only. You will most probably have to use VBA regardless of any trick you might pull off with the worksheet functions. Your only escape is to use a fixed Cell as reference (for example "A1") in that case you CAN use the trick with holding the shift key. It just wont work with names ranges...